# Powershell - Returning/Transferring an object from ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

I am currently able to transfer the file .. but somehow the content is being left out. I think that object is not being returned properly but cannot figure it out.

```
$folder1 = "<external server>"
$folder2 = "<local path>"

# Get all files under $folder1, filter out directories
$firstFolder = Get-JFSChildItem $folder1 | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }

    $firstFolder | ForEach-Object {
    # Check if the file, from $folder1, exists with the same path under $folder2
    If (!(Test-Path($_.FullName.Replace($folder1, $folder2))))
    {
        $fileSuffix = $_.FullName.TrimStart($folder1)
        Write-Host "$fileSuffix is only in folder1"
        Receive-JFSItem $fileSuffix -destination $folder2
    }

}
```

Error: Receive-JFSItem : No such file; No such file.

Error: Receive-JFSItem <<<<  $fileSuffix -destination $folder2

Answer (score 1):

You are using `TrimStart` wrongly. `TrimStart` accepts a **set of symbols** to trim from the argument, and you expect to trim the folder name as an exact string from its beginning. You should instead replace `$folder1` with empty string in `$_.fullname`.

```
If (!(Test-Path($_.FullName.Replace($folder1, $folder2))))
{
    $fileSuffix = $_.FullName.Replace($folder1,"")
    Write-Host "$fileSuffix is only in folder1"
    Receive-JFSItem $fileSuffix -destination $folder2
}
```

Comment: thanks but content of the files is still not being transferred.

Error: Receive-JFSItem : No such file; No such file.
Error: +                 Receive-JFSItem <<<<  $fileSuffix -destination $folder2
Error:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Receive-JFSItem], SftpException
Error:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Rebex.Net.SftpException,MVPSI.Commands.ReceiveJFSItemCommand

Comment: If so, read manuals on `Receive-JFSItem` better, perhaps it demands full name of the file, and you are trying to feed it only base name. Try `Receive-JFSItem $_.fullName -destination $folder2`, or just `$_`.